# Unable to load child states in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I am facing a very peculiar problem in angular1 and it might need a lot context to understand for someone to answer. I have been working on angular for around 4 weeks now but a very strange problem entangles me.

I have a left vertical menu on a page and a click on it loads the content on right side of the page.

On each click I initiate a state. In this case

```
$state.go("contrat-synthese", {
   id: offer.refEboard
}, {
   reload: true
});
```

The above peice of a code is inside a function which works on the click.

The state "contrat-synthese" is shown below

```
angular.module('engcApp').config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
   var lotSelectionState = "synthese-lot";

   $stateProvider.state('contrat-synthese', {
     parent: 'contrat-lots-resume',
     url: '/synthese',
     views: {
       'content@contrat-lots-resume': {
         templateUrl: 'app/entities/views/synthese/synthese.html',
       },
       'synthese-detail@contrat-synthese': {
         templateUrl: 'app/entities/views/synthese/synthese-details.html',
         controller: 'ContratSyntheseDetailsController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
       },
       'synthese-lots-navigation@contrat-synthese': {
         templateUrl: 'app/entities/views/common/contrat-lots-navigation.html',
         controller: 'ContratLotsNavigationController',
         controllerAs: 'vm',
         resolve: {
           afficherLotComplet: function() {
             return false;
           },
           afficherAnneeComplet: function() {
             return false;
           },
           afficherSelectionAnnee: function() {
             return true;
           },
           afficherLots: function() {
             return true;
           },
           stateNameToUse: function() {
             return lotSelectionState;
           }
         }
       },
       'synthese-services@contrat-synthese': {
         templateUrl: 'app/entities/views/synthese/synthese-services.html',
         controller: 'ContratSyntheseServicesController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
       }
     }
   }).state(lotSelectionState, {
     parent: "contrat-synthese",
     params: {
       lots: null
     },
     views: {
       'synthese-composition-lot@contrat-synthese': {
         templateUrl: 'app/entities/views/synthese/synthese-composition.html',
         controller: 'ContratSyntheseCompositionController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
       },
       'synthese-volumes-lot@contrat-synthese': {
         templateUrl: 'app/entities/views/synthese/synthese-volumes.html',
         controller: 'ContratSyntheseVolumesController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
       },
       'synthese-modules-lot@contrat-synthese': {
         templateUrl: 'app/entities/views/synthese/synthese-modules.html',
         controller: 'ContratSyntheseModulesController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
       },
       'synthese-formules-lot@contrat-synthese': {
         templateUrl: 'app/entities/views/synthese/synthese-formules.html',
         controller: 'ContratSyntheseFormulesController',
         controllerAs: 'vm'
       },
     }
   });
 }]);
```

But when I call the state go on page load it is not able to load the **lotSelectionState** in the synthese state above.

I just don't understand why it is not able to load the states when I call it from outside.

Also child states are not loaded when I click on the link again on the left banner.

Solution I tried for the second case, I tried the following approach:

```
state.go("contrat-synthese", {
  id: offer.refEboard
}, {
  reload: true
});
```

However why am I not able to load the child state? I am so confused :(

Can provide and explain more if needed.

Comment: Do you have tag  `<ui-view></ui-view>` in your parent template?

Comment: By parent you mean "contrat-lots-resume"?

Comment: Yes exactly, `contrat-lots-resume`

Comment: Yes. I have tag in it and it has all the views except the first one.